# Can I run the PECL version and the composer version of Protobuf in PHP at the same time?

Tags: php, protocol-buffers

I am currently using Protobuf in production via the PECL installation. My team has requested that we relax that installation requirement for CI & development environments because upgrading/downgrading PECL versions can be a timesink. The Composer package `google/protobuf` seems to be the right choice here, since it is easy to install and upgrade.

If we run both the PECL extension and the Composer package at the same time, which is going to be chosen for usage at runtime?